# Self homeomorphism of $\mathbb CP^1$ holomorphic a.e

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Suppose $\varphi:\mathbb CP^1\to \mathbb CP^1$ is a homeomorphism holomorphic on a connected open subset $U\subset \mathbb CP^1$ with $\mathbb CP^1\setminus U$ of zero measure.

Is it true that $\varphi$ is holomorphic on the whole $\mathbb CP^1$ (so it is a projective transformation)?

If no, what kind of assumptions of $U$ would suffice? (for example $\mathbb CP^1\setminus U$ has Hausdorff dimension $\le 1$?)

Comment: Answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/120118/30186) should be relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Following the links of Wojowu, the answer to this question is negative for the case of self-homeomorphisms of $\mathbb C^1$, here it is:

[Functions holomorphic on a region minus a Cantor set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97138/functions-holomorphic-on-a-region-minus-a-cantor-set/120133#120133)

So by extending the self-homeo to $\mathbb CP^1$ the answer is negative for $\mathbb CP^1$ as well. To have a positve answer, one has to require indeed that the Hausdorff dimension of $\mathbb CP^1\setminus U$ is less than $1$. (the case of $\dim=1$ seems to be still open)